# zum gänzlich__ Niedergleiten (last word unclear)

Tags: meaning

Title has a partial quotation from Kafka:

> ... zum gänzlich__ Niedergleiten ...

I am working an exercise for the adjective ending.  But am curious the gender of Niedergleiten (guess I don't need to know it, but want to know if neuter or masculine).  Also, that is a VERY hard word to find as a noun (or at all) in dictionaries.  I gather it has something to do with the covers slipping off the bed.  But what does Niedergleiten mean.  And is it some sort of participle of a verb or something?  [I did try researching this on the Net and in books.]

Comment: I recommend to add [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/niedergleiten) to the essential references to query.

Comment: Thanks both for your thoughtful answers.  I guess the literal translation to English would be "downsliding" or the like.  It's an "-ing" nominalization.  (Present participle?  I admit to not knowing all the grammar terms even for English...lack of Latin training for us faule Amis.)  And they are all neuter.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find a noun in the dictionary, check if you can find its last component. That's *gleiten* and it's a verb. Actually, singular nouns ending in *-en*, *-ern* or *-eln* are hot candidates for being nominalized infinitives.

So the gender is neuter as all nominalized infinitives are neuter.

For looking up random verbs, I recommend [this tool.](https://verblisten.de/)

---

FYI, participles work like adjectives so they have any gender you want. Same for the Gerundivum. (NOT: Gerundium. German doesn't have such a thing.)

Answer (score 0):

Niedergleiten is a compound noun. This means:

- It is a noun. You can see this from the fact, that its first letter is a capital letter although it's not the first word of a sentence.
- It consists of two or more parts, of which at least the last one must be a noun too.

The grammatical gender of a German compound noun is always the gender of the last part. This rule is a hard rule with no exceptions, so its really easy to remember it.

Some often-used compound nouns are listed in dictionaries, but most of them are not. German dictionaries would have many thousands of pages if every ever used compound noun would be listed in them, because there are so many, and because they can get really long, like [Rindfleischetikettierungsüberwachungsaufgabenübertragungsgesetz](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Rindfleischetikettierungs%C3%BCberwachungsaufgaben%C3%BCbertragungsgesetz) or [Grundstücksverkehrsgenehmigungszuständigkeitsübertragungsverordnung](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Grundst%C3%BCcksverkehrsgenehmigungszust%C3%A4ndigkeits%C3%BCbertragungsverordnung).

So, what are the parts of *Niedergleiten?*

- [nieder (adjective and adverb)](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/nieder), [nieder- (prefix)](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/nieder-)
  As a single word this is either an adjective or an adverb. If used as an adjective, it means *"low"* (*der niedere Tisch = the low table; niedere Instinkte = low instincts*). The adverb means *"down"* (*er legt sich nieder = he lays down; Reißt die Mauern nieder! = Tear down the walls!*)
  As prefix of compound words it inherits the meaning of the adverb and has in addition also some extra meaning:

  - downward movement (*niederknien = kneel down*)
  - verbally bash someone (*jemanden niederbrüllen = to shout someone down*)
  - to destroy (*niederbrennen = burn down*)
- [gleiten (verb)](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/gleiten), Gleiten (noun)
  The verb *gleiten* means to glide or to slide (*Er gleitet mit dem Segelflugzeug durch die Lüfte. = He glides through the air in a glider. - Sie glitt langsam in den Schlaf. = She slowly slipped into sleep.*)
  Wiktionary has no entry for the noun *Gleiten,* but this is a simple derivation of the verb. It is a nominalized verb, i.e. a verb used as a noun. There are many mechanisms to nominalize verbs, and the simplest is to just write it as it is, but with an uppercase first letter. This is always possible for verbs of movement (gehen, reiten, schwimmen, fliegen, kriechen, ...) and the nominalized form is just the name of that movement, and its gender is always neuter.
  So, it's **das Gleiten = the glide** (*Er genoss das Gleiten. = He enjoyed the glide.*)

And because we now know, that the last part of *Niedergleiten* is a neuter noun, we know, that the whole word also must be a neuter noun. And it means: *"the downglide"*

---

So, what is the ending of *gänzlich__* in this nominal Group?

> ... zum gänzlich__ Niedergleiten ...

The contraction *»zum«* is a short form of the prefix *»zu«* and the definite dative article *»dem«* which could be masculine or neuter. But we already know, that the core of the nominal group is neuter, so we also have to interpret the article as a neuter article.

So, for the adjective *gänzlich__,* which is an attribute of the noun *Niedergleiten,* we know these grammatical properties:

- comparison: positive (it's neither comparative nor superlative)
- definiteness/declension: There is a definite article (*dem*), so we need weak declension
- number: singular (only one *Niedergleiten*, not two or more)
- gender: neuter (*»das Niedergleiten«* is a neuter compound noun)
- case: dative (the preposition *zu,* that is contained in the contraction *zum* always needs its inner object to be in dative case)

So, we know all five properties that are needed to decline the adjective *gänzlich,* and we look up the correct declension in a declension table like this: [declension of the adjective *gänzlich*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:g%C3%A4nzlich). And for the combination of these five properties we find:

> **gänzlichen**
> ... zum **gänzlichen** Niedergleiten ...

> Es fehlte nicht viel zum gänzlichen Niedergleiten.
> *It did not lack much to the complete down sliding.*

> Als Gregor Samsa eines Morgens aus unruhigen Träumen erwachte, fand er sich in seinem Bett zu einem ungeheueren Ungeziefer verwandelt. Er lag auf seinem panzerartig harten Rücken und sah, wenn er den Kopf ein wenig hob, seinen gewölbten, braunen, von bogenförmigen Versteifungen geteilten Bauch, auf dessen Höhe sich die Bettdecke, **zum gänzlichen Niedergleiten** bereit, kaum noch erhalten konnte. ...
>
> When Gregor Samsa awoke one morning from restless dreams, he found himself transformed into a monstrous vermin in his bed. He lay on his armor-like hard back and, lifting his head a little, saw his bulging, brown belly, divided by arched stiffeners, at the height of which the bedspread, ready **to slide down completely**, could barely maintain itself. ...

Comment: I would say "Niedergleiten"  is the nominalization of the compound verb ["niedergleiten"](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/niedergleiten).

Comment: And that verb is probably on its way to becoming obsolete.

Comment: That's a very long answer that completely omits the term *infinitive*, which it shouldn't. (Because, just like it does, it doesn't answer the core of the question)

Comment: @tofro: Wie kommst du darauf, dass es in der Frage um Infinitive ginge? Gefragt wurde nach der Endung des Adjektivs und nach der Wortart und der Bedeutung von *Niedergleiten.* All das habe ich beantwortet. Ich wüsste nicht einmal, wie in den Ausdruck *»Infinitiv«* sinnvoll in einen Text einbauen sollte, der eine Frage nach Adjektivendungen, Wortarten und Bedeutungen beantworten soll.

Comment: Ich komme darauf, weil "Niedergleiten" ein nominalisierter Infinitiv ist. Um Adjektive geht es in der Frage nur nebenbei.